# Issue in applying condition expression to all band values in Google Earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, expression, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-classification, band

I want to apply the following condition statement to all the pixels of an indices image having only 1 band. The condition is as follows-

[image: Condition I want to apply]

For that first I have calculated the mean value of my image. Next I have printed the bands existing and then used the expression by substituting the band values.

```
var mean = MNDWI.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),clip_layer,28);
print('mean', mean)

var band_names = MNDWI.bandNames();
print(band_names)

var index = MNDWI

var recode = ee.Image().expression(
'(mean > 0 and index >= mean) or ' +
'(mean <= 0 and index >= (mean**5 - 0.02)) ' +
'? 254 : 0', {
mean: mean, 
index: index
})

Map.addLayer(recode)
```

Here (MNDWI) represents the index, and "B3" is the single band that index is having which can be observed in the print statement output.

[image: Print output values]

But I am getting this error-

Layer error: Image.gt, argument 'image1': Invalid type.
Expected type: Image.
Actual type: Dictionary.
Actual value: {B3=-0.14653535282222163}

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in conversion to float values.

var mean = MBUI.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),clip_layer,28);
print('mean', mean)

var mean_Img = mean.toImage();

var band_names = MBUI.bandNames();
print(band_names)

var index = MBUI.float()

var recode = ee.Image().expression(
'(mean > 0 and index >= mean) or ' +
'(mean <= 0 and index >= (mean**5 - 0.02)) ' +
'? 254 : 0', {
mean: mean_Img,
index: index
})

Answer (score 1):

The error message is almost certainly accurate. `MBUI` probably doesn't have a `B3` band. But your code isn't complete enough to say.

As for the expression, to do power, you don't use `^` but `**`. It also doesn't correctly implement your specified condition. You could perhaps implement it like this:

```
var mean = ee.Image(0)
var index = ee.Image(0)

var recode = ee.Image().expression(
  '(mean > 0 and index >= mean) or ' +
  '(mean <= 0 and index >= (mean**5 - 0.02)) ' +
  '? 254 : 0', {
  mean: mean, 
  index: index
})

Map.addLayer(recode)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd2052391c15a82c4d9d53cc9c1797fc

Comment: I have updated my code as per your suggestion still It fails. Although with a different error this time.

Comment: It helps if you specify which error message. At a glance, this is wrong: `var index = ee.Image(MNDWI[0])`. `MNDWI` is a server-side list of band names. You use `get()` to access elements in a server-side list. Secondly, you don't want a band name at all there. I don't know which bands `MNDWI` contains, but I assume it's only one. If that's the case, just do `var index = MNDWI`.

Comment: yes I have updated the error message also in my question. Second yes MNDWI has 1 single band which is named as B3 there in the print statement image in the question. Third I tried var index = MNDWI, also gives an error. Please help.

Comment: Try to cast both your images to float: `image.float()`

Comment: Can you plase show how to convert to float and do the expression because whenever I am trying it is showing the same error. I tried to use this function https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-float